# How can I disable user interaction with a WheelPicker in Android?

Tags: android, datepicker, picker

I am using this [wheel picker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker) and am trying to find a way to disable user interaction temporarily. So far I have tried the following:

```
    wheelPicker.setEnabled(false);
    wheelPicker.setFocusable(false);
    wheelPicker.setOnClickListener(null);
    wheelPicker.setClickable(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I just extended the WheelPicker class to have an enabled method.

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;

    import com.aigestudio.wheelpicker.WheelPicker;


    public class MyWheelPicker extends WheelPicker {

        boolean enabled = false;

        public MyWheelPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
            if(enabled == true){
                super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setEnabled(boolean enabled){
            this.enabled = enabled;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
wheelPicker.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Comment: No method exists for .setDescendantFocusability for the Wheel Picker.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with "wheel picker" - BLOCK_DESCENDANTS works for standard DatePicker. Sorry!

Comment: Try to place wheelPicker inside Layout, and then use setDescendantFocusability for Layout.

Comment: This does not work either. Thanks for your attempted help though